# Equation relating voltage and minimum rpm needed for generating 1V using a magnet around copper wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I was wondering if there is any equation or law or something that relates the minimum rpm needed when a magnet spins around a copper wire to generate 1 volt?

In other words, how fast does the magnet have to move around the copper wire to generate 1V?

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle: *1 volt is induced in a loop when the magnetic flux through the loop changes at a rate of 1 weber per second, i.e. 1 tesla times square meter per second*.

Provided you have a 1x1 cm loop, in a 0.5 T field of a pair of very strong neodymium magnets, and the loop has 100 turns, the overall magnetic flux through all the coil turns would be up to 0.005 Wb = 0.005 Tm². To induce sinusoidal voltage with 1 V peak, its angular velocity must be 200 radians/s. This is roughly 1900 RPM.

Such an estimate is rather easy in the case of a relatively small loop in a nearly homogeneous magnetic field, one rotating with regards to the other one. If this is not the case, the results will strongly depend the geometry of your setup. Note that the magnetic field intensity usually drops quite fast above the surface of a single magnet.